# Knockout Binding with Multiple If statements

Tags: web, knockout.js, data-binding, conditional-statements

I am applying binding on a style and have succeeded in making the background colour change based on two scenarios. At present it says if the status is 'START', make the background #d10000, else make the background #93d667.

```
style: { background: ManagerStatus() == 'START' ? '#d10000' : '#93d667' }
```

I would like the following functionality:

If START, make #d10000
else if CONTINUE, make #93d667
else make #f7f7f7

How do I achieve these multiple case statements in Knockout binding?

Regards

Alexandra

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys. For future reference someone showed me that you can actually have multiple cases in the data-bind attribute:

{background: ManagerStatus() == 'START' ? '#d100000' : (ManagerStatus() == 'CONTINUE' ? '#93d667' : '#f7f7f7')}

Alexandra

Answer (score 0):

You avoid filling your html with conditional logic and create a knockout computed observable in your viewmodel like so:

```
// or however your viewModel is currently set up.
var viewModel = {
   ManagerStatus: ko.observable() 
}

viewModel.statusBackground = ko.computed(function() {
    status = this.ManagerStatus(),

    switch (status) {
        case "START": return "#d10000";
        case "CONTINUE": return "#93d667";
        default: return #f7f7f7;
    }
}, viewModel);
```

html

```
style: { background: statusBackground }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by nesting two ternary operator expressions. But doing so it's not a good idea: it's much better to modify your View Model, and include a computed observable that returns the backgraound color. Something like this:

```
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.ManagerStatus = ko.observable();
  self.backgroundcolor = ko.computed(function() {
     ManagerStatus() == 'START'
        ? '#d10000' : ManagerStatus() == 'CONTINUE'
                      ? '#93d667' : '#f7f7f7';
  });
  return self;
};
```

The binding would be like this:

```
style: { background: backgroundcolor }
```

Note that you in this case can use a [pure computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html), instead of a regular [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

*NOTE: I've shown how to write a nested ternary operator, and you could include it in the binding expression. But, if it looks ugly in a view model definition, it's even more ugly in a binding expression. In fact, I wouldn't write it like this in the view model definition. Much better to use chained `if else` or `switch` to make it more readable.*